# I want to rank document and store them in a list in python

Tags: python, sorting

I am just a beginner in python. I have document `score= {1:0.98876, 8:0.12245, 13:0.57689}` which is stored in dictionary. The keys are corresponding to a series of document id and the values are corresponding to the score for each document id. How do I rank the document based on the scores?

```
inverse=[(value, key) for key, value in score.items()]
fmax=max(inverse)
```

I already found the maximum values by using the method above which return:

```
(0.98876,1)
```

But what I want is to rank the documents and store in a list:

```
{(0.98876,1),(0.57689,13),(0.12245,8)}
```

Comment: your output structure is a set, not a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sorted(score.items(), key=lambda x:-x[1])
```

should do the trick

The order of the elements in a dictionary is not defined, so the result of the sorting has to be stored in a list (or an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)).

You should convert it to a list of tuples using items(). With sorted() you can sort them, the key parameter tells it to sort according to the inverse of the second tuple element.

Full example:

```
>>> score= {1:0.98876, 8:0.12245, 13:0.57689}
>>> sorted(score.items(), key=lambda x:-x[1])
[(1, 0.98875999999999997), (13, 0.57689000000000001), (8, 0.12245)]
>>> print [(y,x) for (x,y) in _]
[(0.98875999999999997, 1), (0.57689000000000001, 13), (0.12245, 8)]
```

This also shows how to reverse the elements in the tuple if you really want to do that.

Comment: *dictionary cannot be sorted*, that's something new, try `sorted(score)`. Also `sorted` takes any iterable not necessarily a list, so `.iteritems` would do just fine in python-2.x

Comment: sorted(score) returns a sorted list of keys. With "can not be sorted" I meant that a dictionary has no defined order, so the result of the sorting has to be a list. That was a bit sloppy of me.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to modify original list `inverse` then use `inverse.sort(reverse=True)`.
If you want to produce a new list and leave original list untouched, use `sorted(inverse, reverse=True)`.

You don't need an intermediate list, however, just use `score`:

```
>>> sorted(score.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
[(1, 0.98876), (13, 0.57689), (8, 0.12245)]
```

Answer (score 0):

After your inverse method, this would do the trick:

```
ranked = inverse.sort()
```

And here's some more info on sorting in python: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Answer (score 0):

Sort the inverse list:

```
inverse.sort()
```

This will return the list in ascending order, if you want it in reverse order, reverse it also:

```
inverse.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

`inverse.sort(reverse=True)`

have a look [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) for more info on sorting

Answer (score 0):

if you want rank itens in dict:

```
score = {1:0.98876, 8:0.12245, 13:0.57689}
# get a list of items...
list = score.items()
print list
[(8, 0.12245), (1, 0.98875999999999997), (13, 0.57689000000000001)]

# Sort items.
list.sort()
print list 
[(1, 0.98875999999999997), (8, 0.12245), (13, 0.57689000000000001)]
# reverse order
list.reverse()
print list
[(13, 0.57689000000000001), (8, 0.12245), (1, 0.98875999999999997)]
```